# Method not found in base class

Tags: delphi

Как исправить вот такую ошибку? Delphi выделяет вот эту процедуру:

```
procedure AppIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean); override;
```

И пишет: **Method 'AppIdle' not found in base class.**

```
     private
        fchecks: TList;
        fedits: TList;
        function Aggregate: string;

      public
        procedure AppIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean); override;
      end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите директиву `override`.

> Директива Override определяет метод класса как замена так же
>   названного метода в родительском классе.

Если в родительском классе нету метода `AppIdle` то и директива `override` не требуется.